# Database and DB Engines

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, db2, selection

Which are the best available choices for Databases and DB engines and what all factors should be considered while selecting a database and DB engine ?

Comment: The question too broad. Provide us your scenario. We could help you choose best database engine.

Comment: Consider the database requirements under two scenarios : 1. Large data requirement for an enterprise.   2. Database with high performance and low footprint.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

SQLite seems to be a pretty good choice for most people.  Check out [this](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) page to see if it's appropiate for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on

- the amount and type of data you want to store
- the operating environment (cloud / single server)
- the scalability you need
- the development effort you want to invest
- the complexity of the query language you need

e.g. if you need a very small database with simple queries a SQLlite database might be sufficient, but if you have complex queries with lots of relations MySQL or Oracle might be a more reasonable choice.

I would also look into NoSQL databases like mongodb for scalablity and performance.